# Angular(2/4/5/6) Convert array of timeslots into time range

Tags: angular, string, switch-statement

Hi thanks for all your answers! Here's my updated solution based on your inputs. Thanks!

```
getTime(apptTime) {
   const fields = apptTime.split("-");
   const startingTime = this.formatTime(+fields[0]);
   const endingTime = this.formatTime(+fields[1]);

   return startingTime + " - " + endingTime;
}

formatTime(time) {
    if (time < 12) {
      return time === 0 ? "12am" : time + "am";
    } else {
      return time === 12 ? time + "pm" : time - 12 + "pm";
    }
  }
```

I have a string array => **appt_timeslots = ["09-12", "12-15", "15-18", "18-21"]**
That retrieved from the backend and I would like to display it as radio buttons like so:

[image]

**appt.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let appt of appt_timeslots" [ngSwitch]="appt">
   <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn btn-secondary active btn-radio btn-color">
      <input ngbButton type="radio" name="timeslot" value="{{ appt }}"/>
         <span *ngSwitchCase="'09-12'">9am - 12pm</span>
         <span *ngSwitchCase="'12-15'">12pm - 5pm</span>
         <span *ngSwitchCase="'15-18'">3pm - 6pm</span>
         <span *ngSwitchCase="'18-21'">6pm - 9pm</span>
   </label>
</ng-container>
```

Is there a better way to get my timeslots so that I can display am/pm and the dashes instead of using switch case?
So that it can cater for other time slots too (E.g. 2pm - 4pm) and I don't have to manually add another switch case to cater for the new one.
Appreciate your help!

Comment: Maybe to the time mapping in typescript instead. Make a dictionary with keys = `appt_timeslots` values and values = the 9am - 12pm strings. eg. `{"09-12":"9am - 12pm", ...}`. then you can just do <span>{{dict[appt]}}</span>

Comment: With the time i got now, i was able to do like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodel-form-8hyfqc , please extend this one as per your requirement if it helps you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Here's a possible approach.

First I store the backend data as it is.

Then I will created an object with the backend data as the value and a display text based of the value. For example for an element of the backend array `'09-12'`, I create an object `{value:'09-12', text: '9am-12pm'}`

### Your ts file:

```js
 backendData =  ["09-12", "12-15", "15-18", "18-21"] //Data from the backend
 appt_timeslots = []  //This will be our object

 //I do the rest in ngOnInit but that's just for the example.
 ngOnInit() { 

    this.backendData.forEach(e => {
      var text = this.getTextFromValue(e);
      this.appt_timeslots.push({value: e, text: text});
    })
    console.log(this.appt_timeslots);
  }

 getTextFromValue(value:string){

    var timeSlots = value.split("-");
      var formattedTime = timeSlots.map(time => {
        time = this.setAMorPM(time);
        return time
      });

      var result = formattedTime.join("-")
      return result
  }

  setAMorPM(number: string){

    if(parseInt(number) > 12)
      number = (parseInt(number) - 12).toString() + 'pm';
    else
      if(parseInt(number) == 0)
        number = "12am"
      else  
        if(number[0]=='0')
        {
          number = number.slice(1);
          number += 'am';
        }

    return number
  }
```

We create an object based off the backend data each element, and push it to an array of object (`appt_timeslots` ).

The two functions `getTextFromValue()` and `toAMorPM()` only serve to create the text based on the value, I split them up for readability.

### Your HTML file:

Now you just need to loop through your array of object and interpolate the value or the text when needed, like so:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let appt of appt_timeslots" [ngSwitch]="appt.value">
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn btn-secondary active btn-radio btn-color">
     <input ngbButton type="radio" name="timeslot" value="{{ appt.value }}"/>
        <span *ngSwitchCase="appt.value">{{appt.text}}</span>
  </label>
</ng-container>
```

---

Note: The functions can probably be written in more concise way, but I think approach makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

I like using Pipe for transforming, this one dont have check for format but will work for you

```js
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({
      name: 'timeslot'
    })
    export class TimeslotPipe implements PipeTransform {

      transform(value: string): any {
        const times = value.split('-');
        return `${this.generateTimeString(times[0])} - ${this.generateTimeString(times[1])}`;
      }

      private generateTimeString(hourValue: string): string {
        const suffix = +hourValue - 12 > -1 ? 'pm' : 'am';
        const twelveFormat = +hourValue - (suffix === 'pm' ? 12 : 0);
        return `${twelveFormat}${suffix}`;
      }
    }
```

and .html

```html
<p *ngFor="let slot of timeslots">{{slot | timeslot}}</p>
```